# Outlook 7 html email add vertical space between table tds tags

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have created a html template to send it as a newsletter email, but when tested with outlook, a white space between all table td is added. I have searched a lot and this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org

/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Document</title>

</head>
<body>

<table width="684" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
<td align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width: "161px" style= "line-height:0">
<img src="image1.jpg" style="display: block;" />
</td>

<td align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width: "523px" style= "line-height:0">
<img src="image2.jpg" style="display: block;" />

</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

[image]

What can cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The html is still not quite right. This:

```
<table width='684' border='0' cellspacing='0' border-collapse: collapse; cellpadding='0' border-collapse: collapse; align='center'>
```

Should be this:

```
<table width='684' border='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse: collapse;' cellpadding='0' align='center'>
```

It's probably the unclosed tag:

```
<img src="image1.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not the problem, I have edited the question

Comment: Could be that you're specifying the width of the td. Try setting the width of the image and letting the browser work out the td width. Also check the images, do either the left or right have a small white border?